# Trouble using update-rc.d to change Debian startup order

Tags: debian, startup-scripts

I have a Debian Wheezy system on which I want Tomcat to start after MySQL.

In the default runlevel **2**, they are named as follows in **/etc/rc2.d**:

```
S16tomcat7
S18mysql
```

I can get the desired effect, at least temporarily, by manually renaming the tomcat7 link:

```
S18mysql
S20tomcat7
```

However I want to be able to do this with the **update-rc.d** command. I believe this will be the best way to make it work for all runlevels, and after package upgrades. I've tried the following:

```
update-rc.d tomcat7 defaults 20
```

also

```
update-rc.d tomcat7 defaults 20 1
```

as these didn't work, I tried:

```
update-rc.d tomcat7 remove    
update-rc.d tomcat7 defaults 20
```

The remove command successfully removed tomcat7, but the above command resulted in it stubbornly returning to `S16tomcat7`!

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`update-rc.d(8)` enables or disables services, while the ordering of services is handled by `insserv(8)`, and can be customized by editing the LSB header of the Tomcat service and setting/adding:

```
Required-Start: mysql
```

Further reference can be found [here](http://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts).

Comment: Works a treat, thanks. My only concern with editing `/etc/init.d/tomcat7` is whether or not a future apt-get upgrade will overwrite it? For anyone else with this problem, note that I needed to `update-rc.d` remove/add as above, and the relevant line looks like this: `Required-Start: $local_fs $remote_fs $network mysql`

Comment: As per Debian policy, no update should ever edit/remove/replace a user modified configuration file, you should be offered the choice to review the differences, apply the upstream changes or keep yours untouched.